# How to delete text between two matching strings inclusive (only first occurence) that is at the very beginning of the file?

Tags: shell, awk

I am trying to remove the text between `/*` and `*/` that is at the beginning of the file. There can be `white spaces` or `new lines (\n)` before or in-between `/*` and `*/`.

I tried following but doesn't work when space or new lines are there.

```
sed '/^\/\*/,/\*\//d' file
```

Sample file:

```
   /*******
delete
bla

***
  */
/* do not */
print "hi"
/*******
dont delete
****/
```

Expected output:

```
/* do not */
print "hi"
/*******
dont delete
****/
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex to remove multi line comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458785/regex-to-remove-multi-line-comments)

Comment: It doesn't help. Tried on my file, but it doesn't delete anything.

Comment: Please, avoid changing rules when you have 2 answers https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62843678/revisions

Comment: if the first line is `X  /* blah...`, is `X` supposed to be removed from output? What about the spaces immediately following `X` ?

Comment: What should the output be if the first line of the input file is `print "/* uh-oh */"`? You need a parser for whatever language your input file is written in to do this job robustly.

Answer (score 1):

If `ed` is available.

```sh
printf '%s\n' '/^[[:space:]]*\//;/^[[:space:]]*\*\//d' ,p Q | ed -s file.txt
```

- Change `Q` to `w` to edit the file.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box, this will produce the output you want from the input you provided:

```
$ awk 'f; /\*\//{f=1}' file
/* do not */
print "hi"
/*******
dont delete
****/
```

but consider also this more general approach:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ rec = (NR>1 ? rec ORS : "") $0 }
END {
    $0 = rec

    gsub(/@/,"@A"); gsub(/{/,"@B"); gsub(/}/,"@C")
    gsub(/\/\*/,"{"); gsub(/\*\//,"}")

    sub(/^[[:space:]]*{[^}]*}[[:blank:]]*\n/,"")

    gsub(/}/,"*/"); gsub(/{/,"/*")
    gsub(/@C/,"}"); gsub(/@B/,"{"); gsub(/@A/,"@")

    print
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
/* do not */
print "hi"
/*******
dont delete
****/
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56658441/1745001 for an explanation of what those gsub()s are doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk 'BEGIN{f=-1} /^ *\/\*+/{f++}f' file
```

```
/* do not */
print "hi"
/*******
dont delete
****/
```

Comment: Did not work for me. Do you have white space before first `/*`?

Comment: Post edited accordingly

Comment: Not sure why, but still doesn't work for me on the same file.

Comment: Works even with 'mawk', with exactly the source file you provide. Are you on windows ?